# How to detect Admob Interstitial ads is clicked by user?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, onclicklistener

I am developing an android app where i am showing interstitial ads from Admob.
I have to detect whether interstitial ads is clicked by user or not...?
I have tried 
https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/interstitial

but i can't find any listener for ads onClick. 
I have also tried @override touch method of android but @override touch method doesn't work on interstitial ads as interstitial ads are covering whole screen. 
Can anyone suggest me any method or listener to detect user's click on interstitial  ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onAdClicked()` method is available in adListener of google interstitial ad.

```
interAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                super.onAdClicked();

        }
    });
```

Comment: At the current time, [onAdClicked] is only used with native ads originating from Google in one of the system-defined formats (App Install or Content), for banners or interstitial ad's (Ref: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener.html#onAdClicked())

Does anybody know how to close a banner or interstitial AdMob ad without opening it? The [X] it’s a joke.